# In Cocos 2d v3 how to join two spirtes

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

How can you stick two sprites together in cocos2d v3, so that when an actionMove is run on on of them they all move together.

I used connectedPivotJointWithBodyA:bodyB:anchorA method but when one sprite moves, the two sprites become detached for a short period of time until the second sprite catches up.

Comment: Without physics: put both of them on the same parent (a CCNode) and run the move action on the parent. With physics: apply to both the same impulse. If they are joined together, it depends on the joint type and its parameters (rigidity of the joint).

Comment: I tried your without physics option, but when I ran action on the parent, the parent moves without children. Children just stay put

Comment: This can't be. Either you didn't addChild the sprites to the parent node that is running the action, or you manually change (and thus override) the sprite positions every frame (update method).

Comment: Im not sure what I am doing wrong. Basically, I have a PhysicsNode and  with three children: ground (static), hedgehog and apple. apple falls on top of the hedgehog and remain there when hedgehog moves . physics for all three sprites are enabled.whats the best way of approaching this problem in cocos2d v3?

Comment: question: why do you need physics for that?

Comment: to simulate falling apples and to detect when apple and Hedgehog collide.

Comment: Both can be done easily without the physics engine but anyway ... you could remove the apple physics body (set it to nil) after colliding with hedgehog and simply add the apple sprite at its current position as child of the hedgehog sprite. Then it'll move with the hedgehog.

Comment: Thank you, it works now. I did not realise it was necessary to set the physics body nil as well. i thought removing from physics node was enough.

Comment: Now Im having trouble adding the apple at a correct position.         



- (BOOL)ccPhysicsCollisionBegin:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair *)pair
                  ericCollision:(CCNode *)eric
                 appleCollision:(CCNode *)apple{

      CGPoint pos = apple.position;
      [apple removeFromParent];
      apple.position=[eric convertToNodeSpace:pos];
     [eric addChild:apple ];
    apple.physicsBody = nil;     


}

but apple is offset. Im i not getting something right?